# Random HTML characters being encoded in emails

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, html-email, quoted-printable

I'm generating an email with PHP that outputs an HTML table. Most of the table comes through fine, but some of the `<` and `>` characters are randomly encoded to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. It doesn't always do it in the same place. Sometimes it just happens in one place, sometimes not at all, and sometimes in multiple places.

Here's a code snippet from the middle of my table as my email client sees it. Note the inserted `&lt; /tr&gt;` that should not be there:

```
<tr>  
  <td>SERVER_SOFTWARE</td>
  <td>Apache/2.2.29 (Red Hat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>SERVER_PROTOCOL</td>
  <td>HTTP/1.1</td>
  &lt; /tr&gt;
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>REQUEST_METHOD</td>
  <td>POST</td>
</tr>
```

And the same segment in the plaintext part of the email: (again, note that `</tr>` somehow gets inserted.)

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.2.29 (Red Hat)
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1 < /tr>
REQUEST_METHOD POST
```

I'm setting it to UTF-8 in the headers before sending:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";
```

(P.S. I was having the exact same problem earlier using `charset=ISO-8859-1`.)

But despite this, it is somehow being displayed in `US-ASCII`:

```
Content-type: text/html;
    charset="US-ASCII"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
```

The PHP script that's generating the email looks like this:

```
//generate $table
$indicesServer = array('PHP_SELF', 'argv', 'argc', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 'SERVER_ADDR', 'SERVER_NAME', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 'REQUEST_METHOD', 'REQUEST_TIME', 'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT', 'QUERY_STRING', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'HTTP_ACCEPT', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', 'HTTP_CONNECTION', 'HTTP_HOST', 'HTTP_REFERER', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'HTTPS', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'REMOTE_HOST', 'REMOTE_PORT', 'REMOTE_USER', 'REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER', 'SCRIPT_FILENAME', 'SERVER_ADMIN', 'SERVER_PORT', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE', 'PATH_TRANSLATED', 'SCRIPT_NAME', 'REQUEST_URI', 'PHP_AUTH_DIGEST', 'PHP_AUTH_USER', 'PHP_AUTH_PW', 'AUTH_TYPE', 'PATH_INFO', 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') ;
$table = '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="#bbb">';
foreach ($indicesServer as $arg) {
    if (isset($_SERVER[$arg])) {
        $table .= '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>' . $_SERVER[$arg] . '</td></tr>' ;
    } else {
        $table .= '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>-</td></tr>' ;
    }
}
$table .=  '</table>' ;

//set up email
$to = [redacted];
$subject = [redacted];
$email_body = "Heres data:" . $table;
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";

//send email
mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

**EDIT:**
I've noticed HTML attributes are getting messed up. It's related to the `quoted-printable` encoding of equals signs. `=` is encoded to `=3D` as expected, but then sometimes the next character is deleted! Thus the following is happening:

`<a href="http://example.com">`
becomes
`<a href=3D"ttp://example.com">`

`<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=1>`
becomes
`<table cellpadding<ellspacingorder=3D"&lt;tr">`

Comment: Have you tried using `charset=ISO-8859-1` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito, yes. Already mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: You're right, sry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is since that's a closing "tr" that shouldn't be there (you have another right after it), some friendly html parser is "helping" you by changing from being a tag into some normal string.

Another thought:

See here: https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200182068-HTML-Formatting-Issues

> 4. Some mail clients, such as Outlook and Thunderbird, appear to insert double spacing line breaks at every line. The reason is that
>      the 'content-transfer-encoding' in MIME is set to 'quoted-printable'
>      which adds Carriage Return Line Feed (CRLF) line breaks to the source
>      content of the email which are characters interpreted by these mail
>      clients. To alleviate this problem, please do the following:
>
> a.  If you can customize the MIME settings for your email, set the
>   'Content-Transfer-Encoding' to '7bit' instead of 'Quoted-Printable.'
>
> b.  Ensure that your content follows the line length limits from item
>   2 above.

I wonder if something is putting a line break in your tag, causing it to be unreadable, then the browser is adding an extra as a replacement.

Can you try this: **change 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' to '7bit'** or leave it out entirely?

Comment: You're referring to the *output* (as it appears in the email). The HTML before it's sent is syntactically correct and does not have that extra `</tr>` in there. Something is inserting it.

Comment: I'd be surprised but - can you post the whole table? I'm convinced there must be some extra tag in there tough, of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: I posted the code used to generate the table. As you can see each row is basically hardcoded.

Comment: If your HTML tags are not properly balanced, the HTML parser in the browser or email client will try to fix things.

Comment: I strongly believe that my HTML is balanced--the PHP code that generates it is at the end of the question, but I'm pretty sure it's clean.

Comment: Added a comment, not sure if it will help.

Comment: Weird. Using `7bit` doesn't actually change the encoding as the email displays it, but it does seem to help with the quotes after equals signs being deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be due to special HTML characters being in the values you're inserting. When you're inserting random text into HTML, and you don't want it to be interpreted as HTML, you should use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to encode it:

```
foreach ($indicesServer as $arg) {
    if (isset($_SERVER[$arg])) {
        $table .= '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>' . htmlentities($_SERVER[$arg]) . '</td></tr>' ;
    } else {
        $table .= '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>-</td></tr>' ;
    }
}
```

Another possibility is that your lines are too long for the mail software. Try adding `"\n"` at the end of each table row:

```
$table .= '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>' . htmlentities($_SERVER[$arg]) . "</td></tr>'."\n" ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wrapped all PHP output as suggested, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: I suspect the problem isn't in the PHP, it's happening in the mail software, just like when the quoted-printable stuff is deleting the character after it.

Comment: Try putting newlines after each table row, as in my updated answer.

Comment: Tried the newlines. No change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing in your script is doing this. If you write the message into a file instead of sending it as mail, do you see the random HTML? It's got to be happening in the mail transfer.

Comment: Agreed--something is happening after departing the script and hitting the inbox. @dgig's answer below seems to fix it... that I can tell.